# Error 1064 in Mysql code

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `apayments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_hash` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `towho` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `money` enum('Pay','Ask') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pay',
  `type` enum('email','text') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'email',
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: `'email',` at the end .. should not have a comma

Comment: If you look in the **Related** sidebar there are a dozen similar questions. How did you miss them when you searched before posting?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma near `email`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `apayments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_hash` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `towho` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `money` enum('Pay','Ask') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pay',
  `type` enum('email','text') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'email'
                                                    ^^^^^^
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

error showing because email having comma try to execute this command

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `apayments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_hash` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `towho` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `money` enum('Pay','Ask') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pay',
  `type` enum('email','text') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'email'

  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```